# how to do secure socket communication Android to laptop

Tags: java, security, sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to do ssl socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786945/how-to-do-ssl-socket-programming)

I am doing communication from android as client and laptop as server through Socket using wireless router.But how if i want to do communication securely. here is my android code in eclipse

```
public class TCPClient implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

     try {

         InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2");

             Log.d("TCP", "C: Connecting...");

             Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr,12345);

             String message = "Hello from Client android emulator";
              try {

                     Log.d("TCP", "C: Sending: '" + message + "'");

                     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);

                     out.println(message);

                     Log.d("TCP", "C: Sent.");

                 Log.d("TCP", "C: Done.");



         } catch(Exception e) {

             Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
                 } finally {

                    socket.close();

                  }
     } catch (Exception e) {

          Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

     }

}

}
```

> here is server code in Netbean that is working and communicating with android. what changes i have to do ?

```
public class TCPDesktopServer implements Runnable{



public static final String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

public static final int SERVERPORT = 12345;



public void run() {

     try {

        System.out.println("S: Connecting...");

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

         while (true) {

             Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

             System.out.println("S: Receiving...");

             try {
                  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                  String str = in.readLine();

                  System.out.println("S: Received: '" + str + "'");
             } catch(Exception e) {

                    System.out.println("S: Error");

                    e.printStackTrace();

             } finally {
                    client.close();
                    System.out.println("S: Done.");
                }
         }

     } catch (Exception e) {

         System.out.println("S: Error");

         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

public static void main (String a[]) {

    Thread desktopServerThread = new Thread(new TCPDesktopServer());

    desktopServerThread.start();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream/CipherInputStream, or if you want a more standardized approach you could try Apache commons (http://commons.apache.org/) where there is a basic implementation of SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You could very easily use the SSLSocket class which is part of the base java distribution. If you are having problems getting certificates to validate, you can user [this](http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/TrustAll.html) tutorial to show you how to allow self-signed certs and non-matching host names.

Comment: sorry but how to resolve                                           InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2"); into hhtps