# How to setup JMeter TCP Sampler with SSL/TLS?

Tags: ssl, tcp, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Getting HTTPS setup in JMeter with SSL is pretty straight forward but same setup is not working for TCP Sampler, any pointer?

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do you need to use the TCP Sampler if HTTP(S) works fine? You'll probably have to implement your own TCP sampler client.

Comment: it's for two different application but a learning stepping stone for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment JMeter TCP Sampler doesn't support SSL protocol, you will either need to write your own implementation or consider switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead.

Reference code to create SSL TCP connection

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

int your_app_port = 1234;
String your_app_host = "localhost";
JsseSSLManager sslManager = (JsseSSLManager) SSLManager.getInstance();
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = sslManager.getContext().getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(your_app_host, your_app_port);
//do what you need with the SSL socket here
```

References:

- [how to do ssl socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786945/how-to-do-ssl-socket-programming)
- [SSLSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)
- [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)