# I want to use JMeter to simulate the TLS handshake process

Tags: ssl, jmeter, tls1.2

I want to modify each step in the TLS handshake process to test whether my tls server meets the specifications.
For example, I want to use JMeter to simulate the first "client_hello" request of TLS, and I can customize the content of the parameters in the TLS protocol in JMeter. For example, I can set the "version" value to "aaabbb", and deliberately fail the negotiation .
Any good ideas?
[handshake process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkmZH.png)

Comment: have a look at this thread, it might have with your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841364/how-to-setup-jmeter-tcp-sampler-with-ssl-tls

Answer (score 0):

As per [SSL Encryption](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl) chapter of JMeter User Manual

> **The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc.** This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.

Therefore if you need to validate the [TLS handshake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Transport_Layer_Security) you will need to manually script the connection logic including low-level transport settings using [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) using [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Example code:

```
def sslContext = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().useTLS().build()

String [] protocols = ['aaabbb']

def f = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, protocols, null, org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)

def client = org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(f).build();

def get = new org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet('https://example.com')

client.execute(get)
```

Demo:

[image]